# Updating Erlang freeBSD port to newer minor version

Tags: erlang, updates, freebsd, ports

I have Erlang OTP version 17 on my freeBSD system. Now I want to update to the newest release of the OTP 17 branch. I don't want to upgrade to OTP 18 (I only need the latest release of OTP 17 with all patches)

Do I achieve this by entering the following command:

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/erlang-runtime17/ && make install clean
```

I'm not very experienced with freeBSD and afraid to destroy something on my system.

Comment: The `erlang-runtime` port is of version `17.5.6.9`. Is it sufficiently recent for you?

Comment: That version is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Erlang from the packages run `pkg install erlang-runtime17`.

To compile it from ports run command you mentioned, just make sure you have to to date ports tree.

Finally, to compile and update Erlang and all its dependencies, first install `portmaster` utility and then run `portmaster erlang-runtime`.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer. How do I determine if I have installed Erlang from ports or from the packages. I can't remember.

Comment: @Jeyhey Hum. You can search for a package cache in `/var/cache/pkg/`. If there is a file `erlang-runtime*.txz`, then you are probably used packages.

Comment: I think I installed it from ports. However, when running the command I get `erlang-runtime17-17.5.6.9_2 pkg(8) must be version 1.6.0 or greater,
but you have 1.3.8. You must upgrade the ports-mgmt/pkg port first`.

Comment: You seen to have pretty old system. Try `pkg install pkg`.

Comment: I tried `cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg` and then `make deinstall reinstall`. Now `cd /usr/ports/lang/erlang-runtime17/ && make install clean` is executing. That's going to take some time.

Comment: This will fail on install stage, because you forgot deinstall. No worries, just `make deinstall`once it fails and then rerun first command.

Comment: Now it says `./rebar: Command not found.` when running `./rebar compile` in my mongooseim directory. I might open a new question for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121273/discussion-between-arrowd-and-jeyhey).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is old qustion. 
but, i strugled with the same, and have another solution: using `portdowngrade`.

With this tool you may downgrade any software in ports, without spoilong `/usr/ports`.

And in my case, I needed some tools from `/usr/ports/lang/erlang`, which are not included into runtime, so i had to find how to install old one. 
And this is very easy:

```
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portdowngrade
make && make install clean
portdowngrade lang/erlang r420247
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portdowngrade/erlang
make config && make && make install clean
```

here I show show how to downgrade to revision "r420247". And this is last for OTP18.

If you run `portdowngrade` without any options, it will ask for information, so you may find the latest for OTP17.